# Document classification on Twitter: LDA or something non-generative?

Tags: classification

On Twitter, I would like to assign weight to users based on how similar their bios are to a topic (e.g. technology would be a topic, the training set would be the bios of users who are known to be interested in technology). I was thinking of using LDA, where I would get the theta value (document-topic association) of the new document (which would be the bio of the Twitter user I want to classify) and use it as the weight. Does this make sense? Should I rather use a discriminative algorithm since classification is supposed to be a discriminative problem?